# Is it possible to cut the unit square in triangles of the same area such that one of the vertices has irrational coordinates?

Tags: geometry, rationality-testing

This may be an easy question, although it stumped some of us over lunch. Consider the unit square and cut it up in several triangles, such that all the triangles have the same area. Is it possible that one triangle has a vertex with irrational coordinates (at least the abscissa or the ordinate, not necessarily both)?

This question was prompted by the theorem that in the cutting above, the number of triangles has to be even. The proof ([that was inspired by this talk by Jim Fowler](https://www.math.univ-paris-diderot.fr/diffusion/_media/meme_aire_p_pair_solution.pdf)) uses that there exists an extension of the 2-adic valuation on $\mathbb{R}$, which follows from the axiom of choice. So we're wondering if it's necessary.

Comment: Just one vertex? The rest have rational coordinates?

Comment: @YuriyS At least one. If there's one there's probably more but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid fractions, consider a square with side-length $3$. Doing so doesn't affect the rationality-irrationality of coordinates.

[image]

The image shows a dissection into six triangles of area $3/2$. The coordinates of the inner vertices are

$$\left(1, \phi^{-2}\right) \qquad \left(\phi^{2},1\right) \qquad \left(2,\phi^{2}\right) \qquad \left(\phi^{-2},2\right)$$

where $\phi := \frac12\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)$, the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), is an irrational number. $\square$